# Add HTML Markup using java Apache PDFBOX

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox

I have been using PDFBOX and EasyTable which extends PDFBOX to draw datatables. I have hit a problem whereby I have a java object with a string of HTML data that I need to be added to the PDF using PDFBOX. A dig at the documentation seems not to bear any fruits.

The code below is a snippet hello world, which I want on the pdf been generated to have H1 formatting.

```
// Create a document and add a page to it
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage( page );

// Create a new font object selecting one of the PDF base fonts
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;

// Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

// Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
        contentStream.drawString( "<h1>HelloWorld</h1>" );
        contentStream.endText();

// Make sure that the content stream is closed:
        contentStream.close();

// Save the results and ensure that the document is properly closed:
        document.save( "Hello World.pdf");
        document.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jerico](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) to format the html to free text while mapping correctly the output of tags.

sample

```
public String extractAllText(String htmlText){
    return new net.htmlparser.jericho
            .Source(htmlText)
            .getRenderer()
            .setMaxLineLength(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            .setNewLine(null)
            .toString();
}
```

Include on your gradle or maven:

```
compile group: 'net.htmlparser.jericho', name: 'jericho-html', version: '3.4'
```

Answer (score 1):

PDFBox does not know HTML, at least not for creating content.

Thus, with plain PDFBox you have to parse the HTML yourself and derive special text drawing characteristics from the tags text is in.

E.g. when you encounter `"<h1>HelloWorld</h1>"`, you have to extract the text `"HelloWorld"` and use the information that it is in a `h1` tag to select an appropriate prime header font and font size to draw that `"HelloWorld"`.

Alternatively you can look for a library doing that HTML parsing and transforming to PDF text drawing instructions for PDFBox, e.g. [Open HTML to PDF](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf).

Comment: @mki are you in a position to create an example using pdfbox and OPEN HTML to pdf, if not no worries I will share the one I will implement.